# Draw GaN e-mode HEMT transistor with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

How can I draw a transistor like the one below using circuitikz?[image: GaN HEMT]

Comment: page 66 of the manual -- http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf

Comment: Notice that *exactly* that symbol is not available. There are thousands of variations of transistor symbols, and time is limited...

Comment: hemt, type: node (node[hemt]{}). Class: transistors.

Comment: See also https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/691